# How to build interactive, 3D graphs in javascript

Tags: javascript, data-visualization

I am building an interactive sports-graphics website and I recently came across [this great 3D baseball vis tool](https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/visuals/pitch3d?player_id=594798) and I am very curious how to make something like this. In particular, I would like to build a similar tool for basketball (that shows shot trajectories).

I don't think stackoverflow is the best place to post this, but I'm not sure where else to ask. Feel free to point me in the right direction, or if the post is okay, I'm happy to hear people's thoughts on how to build a tool like this.

Thanks in advance!!

Edit: for those curious / interested in these types of graphs, here is another tool on the same website [that shows homeruns hit](https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/hr_derby)

Comment: The link you shared is using HTML 5 canvas and web gl . To code something like this you will need a small understanding of matrix mathematics and vectors . Also there's a game development platform called Unity that gives you the ability to compile 3d to HTML 5 canvas. If you know JavaScript here's a 3d library called Three.js https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_morph

Comment: the math is not a problem for me

Comment: it seems like most people that use the webGL API do so with the help of some other library (three.js like you suggested), rather than using the webGL API directly... does that sound right?

Comment: Right! In fact , there's so many libraries.

Comment: I will likely start with three.js. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a lot of sprites/polygons go with **webgl-canvas**. If you do not want to use it directly there are many libraries  to make your life easier such as **pixie.js(2D)** or **three.js**.

If you do not have too many polygons (**<~2000**) you can still go with **svg**. If you are going with this way, your best bet will be going for point cloud (scatter plot with **circles**) or **polygons** where you keep the points attached to the element so you can rotate them on demand and set the points attribute/property (if you'll use d3, it will already add it to the element in the `__data__` property):

```
polygon.__points = [[x1,y1]..];
```

You can either go for `euclidian` angles with `3*3 matrix` or use `quaternions` (a bit faster and avoids gimbal lock). Most likely, your bottleneck will not be these but the **DOM operations**. Here is an example from one of my projects, its bit old (about 6-7 years) but still can demonstrate the idea (click lower left icon when the link opens):

http://www.i-pv.org/1_45/NFKB1

[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbKB3.jpg)

In short, if you are going for fps and shading, then go for webgl.